# process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE always showing undefined on macos

Tags: javascript, node.js, threadpool, libuv

I am running a simple node script -

```
var fs = require('fs');
var start = new Date();
var simulateTime = 1000;

console.log('LIBUV Threads: ', process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE);
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var end = new Date() - start
    console.info('Execution time: %dms', end)
  }, simulateTime);
}
```

I have set the following in package.json -

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=20 & node index.js"
  },
```

However LIBUV threadpool size is always showing undefined. I am running the script by -

```
npm start
```

and node version is v12.9.1.

Thanks

Comment: `set` is for windows, you should use [`export`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x) or [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) module

Comment: Put that in an answer!

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I changed it to export and cross-env one by one, even then I am getting as undefined.

Comment: even with `&& node.. `? (note the double &)

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon - oh yes my mistake i pasted here wrong. I was using && only. It is showing undefined only. Has it something to do with node verison? Thanks

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon - Hey now it is showing 20. Thanks. It is being set to 20 using export and not cross-env.